# cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'hazelcast'

Tags: xml, spring, hazelcast

I am trying to configure Hazelcast with Spring .
I am using separate file for Hazelcast's  xml file configuration , I checked xsd which I configured in XML in this file it contains 'hazelcast' element and also configured as per namespace specification in xsd  and also added 3.3 version of hazelcast , hazelcast-all & hazelcast-spring.

I checked the xsd  file - http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config hazelcast-config-3.3.xsd , I can open and locate the hazelcast element in it.

You can refer hazlecast xml here - https://dzone.com/articles/configuring-hazelcast-within

```
<hazelcast  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config hazelcast-config-3.3.xsd"

           xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"

           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >      
    <group>
        <name>hazelcast</name>
        <password>12345</password>
    </group>
    <properties>
        <property name="hazelcast.logging.type">slf4j</property>
        <property name="hazelcast.jmx">true</property>
        <property name="hazelcast.jmx.detailed">true</property>
    </properties>

    <management-center enabled="false">http://localhost:8080/hazelcast</management-center>



    <map name="HttpRequestsCache">
        <time-to-live-seconds>600</time-to-live-seconds>
        <max-size>1000</max-size>
    </map>






</hazelcast>
```

But getting an error -

Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for element 'hazelcast' of schema namespace 'http://www.hazelcast.com/
     schema/config'
    - cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'hazelcast'.
    - schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'hazelcast-config-3.3.xsd', because

1) could not find the  document; 
2) the document could not be read;
3) the root element of the document is not .

Answer (score 0):

Your XML isn't formatting correctly on the post, but I suspect the problem is

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config hazelcast-config-3.3.xsd"
```

should be

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config/hazelcast-config-3.3.xsd"
```

If you're are adding Hazelcast to a project, it's a far better idea to pick a newer version than 3.3. The current is 3.12.

Plenty working samples [here](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/hazelcast-integration) of Spring to base things on, with correct XML.

Comment: Hi Neil , thanks for the response . I already tried the mentioned syntax earlier without success with 3.10 version. Then I decided to try with lower version as our Spring version is older 3.1.1.RELEASE  .Let me try with other configurations mentioned by you in URL.

Comment: I configured the project with 3.7 version of xmls and worked perfectly. Referred : https://www.baeldung.com/java-hazelcast

Comment: Sorry , for some duration after building the project the issue I  realized as resolved but still not .

Comment: Can you post the new XML ? If it works then stops working, it could be intermittent network issues, so the error message from the logs will be useful also. Perhaps as a new question, and link to it with a comment.

Comment: Thanks , The same xml I used in classpath and in web.xml declared as classpath rather than reference path and without any xml error issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Had same error with Eclipse 2020-06, using 'https' URLs fixed it for me:

```
<hazelcast xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config hazelcast-config-3.6.xsd"
       xmlns="https://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
       xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```